# ROS1 dependency in nav2 tutorial?

Tags: ros-humble, tutorial, nav2

I'm trying to discover Nav2 stack.
I'd like to do a mission/follow-waypoint thing in my own simulation.
I started with the "*Getting Started*" -> "*Running the Example*" after installation of nav2 Ubuntu package for ros2-humble.
I got the error : *"package 'gazebo_ros' not found ..."*
But if I'm not mistaken, this is a ROS1 package. It is used to spawn entity. I did not find a package with the executable, (in my simulation I use `ros_gz_sim` to spawn element).
I probably miss something, could you tell me what it is ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`gazebo_ros` is still used in ROS2. The source code is available here : [gazebo_ros ros2 branch](https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/tree/ros2)

`sudo apt-get install ros-humble-gazebo-ros` should do the job

Comment: thank you.
Unfortunately I cannot install this package, I have gz-tools2 which makes conflict.